# Check if array exist inside an nested array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let arr1 = [['item 1', 'item 2'],['item 3', 'item 4']]
let arr2 = ['item 1', 'item 2']
```

I need to check whether arr2 exist in arr1

Comment: You will have to use some and every. Does the order matter?

Comment: This is a very popular gist that tackle this: https://jsfiddle.net/SamyBencherif/8352y6yw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#some` along with `Array#every`.

```js
let arr1 = [
  ['item 1', 'item 2'],
  ['item 3', 'item 4']
]
let arr2 = ['item 1', 'item 2']
let res = arr1.some(x => x.length === arr2.length && x.every((e, i) => e === arr2[i]));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now If I want to delete that item how can I?

Comment: You can use `arr1.splice(arr1.findIndex(x => x.length === arr2.length && x.every((e, i) => e === arr2[i])), 1)`

Comment: @geekglance No problem.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple you can use the combination of every and some as below, it returns true if exists and false if not

```
arr1.some(i => i.length === arr2.length && i.every(it => arr2.includes(it)))
```

Comment: If I want to delete that item how can i?

Comment: 1 .  You can use findIndex and splice
    `let res = arr1.findIndex(x => x.length === arr2.length && x.every((e, i) => e === arr2[i]));
arr1.splice(0,1)`;

2. you can directly use filter
    `arr1 = arr1.filter(x => x.length !== arr2.length || x.some((e, i) => e !== arr2[i]));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a very quick and easy way to check, you could do:

```
arr1.findIndex(arr => { return JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(arr2) })
```

Which will return the position of arr2 within arr1, or '-1' if it does not exist in arr1

Comment: Quick note: This will only work if you are trying to match the order (which you might be seeing as in JS arrays are ordered)